# data.xml - Output encoding of stream (UTF-8) doesn't match declaration (Cp1252)

Tags: xml, clojure

I'm trying to write some XML to a file using [clojure/data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml)

I have created a leiningen project ([src here](https://github.com/am2605/data-xml-demo)).  The main function looks like this:

```
(defn -main
[]
(let [tags (element :foo {:foo-attr "foo value"}
                  (element :bar {:bar-attr "bar value"}
                           (element :baz {} "The baz value")))]
(with-open [out-file (java.io.FileWriter. "C:/Users/amyers/Desktop/output.xml")]
  (emit tags out-file))))
```

When I run it (on Windows 7 Pro, 64bit), I am getting the following output:

```
C:\Users\amyers\projects\clojure-projects\data-xml>lein run
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Output encoding of 
stream (UTF-8) doesn't match declaration (Cp1252)
```

I am guessing that the underlying Java output stream has Cp1252 as the character encoding but it's trying to write UTF-8 (which is what I want).  How can I write the XML successfully in UTF-8 please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Java.io.FileWriter` seems to use the default encoding of your system, which is `Cp1252`. Instead of using `java.io.FileWriter` directly, you should use `clojure.java.io/writer`, with specifying `:encoding` option.

```
...
(with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer "out.xml" :encoding "UTF-16")]
  (emit tags w))
```

If you should pass `Writer` instance, try to construct an `OutputStreamWriter` on a `FileOutputStream`.

```
...
(with-open [w (java.io.OutputStreamWriter. (java.io.FileOutputStream. "out.xml") "UTF-8")] 
  (emit tags w))
```